# flutter firebase_firestore_ui whereIn exceeds 10

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
  late Query<Map<String, dynamic>> query1;
  late Query<Map<String, dynamic>> query2;
  @override
  void initState() {
    query1 = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection(Constants.blogCollection)
        .where('isApproved', isEqualTo: true)
        .orderBy('likeCount', descending: true);
    query2 = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection(Constants.blogCollection)
        .where('isApproved', isEqualTo: true)
        .where("uid", whereIn: ref.read(userProvider)!.following)
        .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true);
    super.initState();
  }
```

I am using firebase_firestore_ui for pagination firebase whereIn says I exceeded 10 limit My code below is how can I solve this and can you post code?